# How to restore single table from its dump file (xyz.dump) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I tried this command

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d test1  table4.dump
```

and got error

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump.
>   Please use psql.

How to restore the dump file?

Comment: Just feed it to psql as mentioned in my answer - this should solve your problem. You can also use [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) to restore dumps..

Comment: @horse: no need to do this manually ;)
krist: did you try what i suggested in my answer?

Comment: @iLuvLogix i need to restore only single table not a db.

Comment: @krist: You can do the same for a table ;)

Comment: @krist: i updated my answer

Comment: @iLuvLogix, It Works thanks...one more thing Is it possible  to restore the same dump in  AWS redshift through cmd line

Comment: @krist: I updated/edited my answer..

Comment: @krist: I saw you accepted my answer - If it was usefull to you i would appreciate an upvote aswell ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have dumped the table in plain sql format which was designed to feed to psql.

This is not recognized by pg_restore! -> [doc on pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgrestore.html)

For whole db:

```
cat db.txt | psql dbname
```

or

```
psql dbname < db.txt
```

for table:

connect to the db using psql:

```
psql /i path/to/filename
```

will help..

**EDIT/UPDATE:**

You asked for AWS redshift - here's the solution:

Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon Redshift console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/redshift/

- Choose Clusters
- Choose the Table restore tab
- Choose Restore table.
- In the Table restore panel, select a date range that contains the
  cluster snapshot that you want to restore from.